# TypeError: worker() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a subclass and it throws the error:

`TypeError: worker() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

```
class KeyStatisticCollection(DataDownloadUtilities.DataDownloadCollection):
    def GenerateAddressStrings(self):
        pass    
    def worker():
        pass
    def DownloadProc(self):
        pass
```

Comment: [Docstrings are nifty](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), all the cool kids are using them.

Answer (score 170):

Your `worker` method needs 'self' as a parameter, since it is a class method and not a function. Adding that should make it work fine.

Comment: First time I saw that error, I scratched my head for a long time. Then from my experience and confirmation by your answer was able to figure out that my class method with 0 arguments, at runtime, was supplied with 'self' argument, which was giving me this error.

Intricacies of python.

Comment: Still relevant after 8 years lol. I was really scratching my head for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

If the method doesn't require `self` as an argument, you can use the `@staticmethod` decorator to avoid the error:

```
class KeyStatisticCollection(DataDownloadUtilities.DataDownloadCollection):

    def GenerateAddressStrings(self):
        pass    

    @staticmethod
    def worker():
        pass

    def DownloadProc(self):
        pass
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Answer (score 20):

You forgot to add `self` as a parameter to the function `worker()` in the class `KeyStatisticCollection`.

Answer (score 18):

This can be confusing especially when you are not passing any argument to the method. So what gives?

When you call a method on a class (such as `work()` in this case), Python ***automatically*** passes self as the first argument.

Lets read that one more time:
*When you call a method on a class (such as `work()` in this case), Python **automatically** passes self as the first argument*

So here Python is saying, hey I can see that `work()` takes 0 positional arguments (because you have nothing inside the parenthesis) but you know that the `self` argument is still being passed **automatically**  when the method is called. So you better fix this and put that `self` keyword back in.

Adding `self` should resolve the problem. `work(self)`

```
class KeyStatisticCollection(DataDownloadUtilities.DataDownloadCollection):
def GenerateAddressStrings(self):
    pass    
def worker(self):
    pass
def DownloadProc(self):
    pass
```

Answer (score 6):

```
class KeyStatisticCollection(DataDownloadUtilities.DataDownloadCollection):
def GenerateAddressStrings(self):
    pass    
def worker(self):
    pass
def DownloadProc(self):
    pass
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Answer (score 3):

I get this error whenever I mistakenly create a Python class using `def` instead of `class`:

```
def Foo():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
# python thinks we're calling a function Foo which takes 0 args   
a = Foo(x) 

TypeError: Foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Oops!

Answer (score 1):

Check if from method with name method_a() you call method with the same name method_a(with_params) causing recursion

Answer (score 1):

just pass self keyword in def worker(): function

```
class KeyStatisticCollection(DataDownloadUtilities.DataDownloadCollection):
    def GenerateAddressStrings(self):
        pass    
    def worker(self):
        pass
    def DownloadProc(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

another use case for this error is when you import functions within the class definition.  this makes the subsequent function calls a part of the class object.  In this case you can use @staticmethod on the library import function or make a static path call directly to the function.  see example below

In this example "self.bar()" will throw a TypeError, but it can be fixed in two ways

```
# in lib.py
def bar():
  print('something to do')

# in foo.py
class foo():
  from .lib import bar

  def __init__(self):
    self.bar()
```

Option 1:

```
# in lib.py
def bar():
  print('something to do')

# in foo.py
class foo():
  from .lib import bar

  def __init__(self):
    lib.bar()
```

Option 2:

```
# in lib.py:
@staticmethod
def bar():
  print('something to do')

# in foo.py
class foo():
  from .lib import bar

  def __init__(self):
    self.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing Flask Basic auth I got this error and then I realized I had wrapped_view(**kwargs) and it worked after changing it to wrapped_view(*args, **kwargs).

Answer (score 0):

```
 class KeyStatisticCollection():
     def GenerateAddressStrings(self):
         pass
     def worker():
         return blabla
     def DownloadProc(self):
         abc = self.GenerateAddressStrings()
         #abc = GenerateAddressStrings()#error
     blabla = worker()
     #blabla = self.worker()#error
```

i think this is a better explaination about using self param