# python3 Passing function objects as argument

Tags: python-3.x

I've started learning Python3.
Below code snippet gives error -

`TypeError: print() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

```
def myprint(arg):
    print(arg)


def callbk(func, arg):
    func(arg)
    func(arg)


callbk(myprint, 'Hello World')
```

## I could not find any proper solution, I'm not creating any new class here.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884782/typeerror-worker-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-1-was-given

Comment: The code you show works under both Python 2 and Python 3. There's something else you're not showing us. My best guess is that you've redefined `print` somewhere else. If you simply type `print` (and press the return key) at the Python prompt, do you see something like: `<built-in function print>`?