# tkinter button unable to open different python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to run a .py file from another python code using the following sequence.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sys

def open_SS():
    print('processing')
    os.system('cd /home/pi/Desktop/Backup')
    os.system('python p.py')

def close_window(): 
    master.destroy()

master = Tk()

master.minsize(width=500, height=300)

Button(master, text='Exit', command=close_window).grid(row=12, column=6, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='SS', command=open_SS).grid(row=12, column=8, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

The Exit button does the command, but the 'SS' button does not, the word 'processing' does get printed, just the running of the p.py file. I tried running those two os.system commands on a command terminal and it works fine. p.py is supposed to input GPIO signals to a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: why not simply `import p`?

Comment: Also, `cd ...` and `python ...` need to be in the same `os.system` invocation, for example `os.system('cd ...; python ...')`. If you separate them, they are executed in separate shells, and the `cd` performed in the first `os.system()` does not affect the second one.

Comment: Try fully qualified path of your installed python as well as the file in the same command.

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import *

import os

import sys

master = Tk()

def open_SS():

    print('processing')
    os.system("python /home/pi/Desktop/Backup/p.py")

btn=Button(master,text="click here")

btn.grid(row=0,column=1)

btn.bind("<Button>",open_SS)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I had to make a few changes for it to work. This code kept bringing up the error `TypeError: worker() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`. To take care of this, a parameter needs to be given, according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884782/typeerror-worker-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-1-was-given?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). In the end I used `def open_SS(self):
      import p.py` because `os.system` just did not work.

Comment: def open_SS(event):

Comment: some changes in function line