# on_ready() takes at 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, discord.py

I am having errors with this script I am creating it so that people can get the streaming status for free, Here is the code

```py
import discord

token = input("User Token For The Streaming: ")
stream = input("Streaming URL: ")
game = input("Name of game playing: ")
class MyClient(discord.Client):

async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=game, url=stream))
    print('Connected to user: {}'.format(client.user.name))
    print('User Id: {}'.format(client.user.id))

client = MyClient()
client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: worker() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884782/typeerror-worker-takes-0-positional-arguments-but-1-was-given)

Comment: Please add the errors to your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script, maybe it'll be work.
The script:

```
n = 0
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)
        token = input("User Token For The Streaming: ")
        stream = input("Streaming URL: ")
        game = input("Name of game playing: ")
        client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)
    
    @client.event
         async def on_ready():
            await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Streaming(name=game, url=stream))
            print('Connected to user: {}'.format(client.user.name))
            print('User Id: {}'.format(client.user.id))
        
        client.run(token, bot=False)
#n = 0 string is not need to use but i don't know why did i add it.
```